# The number of injective functions if there is not the same number of elements on each side

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having a hard time really understanding the logic. If my domain has 3 elements, and my codomain has 2 elements, how many injective functions are possible? I know there are 3^2 functions possible, but I do not know how to reason after.

Domain = a,b,c and Codomain = a,b

If a has an image, there's only one possibility for b or c to have an image after. That's is how I see it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Draw a picture. Which of the eight functions are injective?

Comment: Your statement "if a has an image..."  is a good start.  Keep going along that route.  Since you are looking for any function, you can just declare that $a$ has image $a$.  Now for $b$?  And for $c$?

Comment: I have 6 injective functions. Is there a formula for this type of operation?

Comment: [edit] the question to show us one of the six injective functions you found.

Comment: You have six injective functions from three elements to two elements? You should design parking lots.

Comment: There are $2^3 = 8$ functions from $A = \{a, b, c\}$ to set $B = \{a, b\}$ since there are two possible images in the codomain for each element of the domain.  Make a list of each such function.  Which of these, if any, are injective?